# Cannot forward after response has been committed when using deferredResult

Tags: java, spring-mvc

In order to implement long polling I've tried different solution and did not acquire any good result.

So I decide to look into asynchronous methods and `DeferredResult`.
Here I implemented `REST` constroller.

```
@Controller("sessionStateRest")
@RequestMapping("ui")
public class SessionStateRest extends BaseRestResource {

    private final Queue<DeferredResult<ModelAndView>> mavQueue = new ConcurrentLinkedQueue<>();

    /**
     * Rest to check session state.
     *
     * @return string with session state
     */
    @RequestMapping(value = "/session")
    public @ResponseBody DeferredResult<ModelAndView> sessionState() {
        final DeferredResult<ModelAndView> stateResult = new DeferredResult<>();
        this.mavQueue.add(stateResult);
        return stateResult;
    }

    @Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)
    public void processQueue() {
        for(DeferredResult<ModelAndView> result: mavQueue) {
            if (null == SecurityHelper.getUserLogin()) {
                result.setResult(createSuccessResponse("Invalidated session"));
                mavQueue.remove(result);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

By idea it should process queue of requests every 5 seconds and `setResult` if condition is true.

Synchronous version would be something like this

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/sync")
public ModelAndView checkState() {
    if (null == SecurityHelper.getUserLogin()) {
        createSuccessResponse("Invalidated session");
    }
    return null; // return something instead
}
```

But after some time I've got an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot forward after response has been committed
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:349) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.
39.jar:7.0.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:339) ~[tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39
.jar:7.0.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:467) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:7.0.3
9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:338) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:7.0.3
9]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.throwable(StandardHostValve.java:428) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:7.
0.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.core.AsyncContextImpl.setErrorState(AsyncContextImpl.java:417) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:
7.0.39]
        at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.asyncDispatch(CoyoteAdapter.java:294) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:7
.0.39]
        at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.asyncDispatch(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1567) [tomcat-embed-c
ore-7.0.39.jar:7.0.39]
        at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:583) [tomcat-embed-cor
e-7.0.39.jar:7.0.39]
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312) [tomcat-embed-core-7.0.39.jar:7.
0.39]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [na:1.7.0_67]
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [na:1.7.0_67]
```

What's the problem? Should I set the timeout for `DeferredResult`?

Comment: You should first make it work **without** the `DeferredResult`, and only then try to add it. I cannot understand what this code could do ... and I am not sure that spring can understand either which is far worse ;-)

Comment: @SergeBallesta I was not able to find a solution for that with asynchronous calls

Comment: What I meant is *first make it work synchonously*

Comment: @SergeBallesta, but that's simple - after all I need just to do basic stuff like in all my controllers - take `SecurityHelper` and get look. I  even have checks in some controllers whether `login` is null or not and return some response corresponding `null` user.

Comment: **You** may know what is the synchronous working version of the above, but **I** don't. What I see is that you have a `@ResponseBody` annotation and that you use `ModelAndView` type results which does not seem coherent. But I cannot guess which is right, and what the synchronous version should return ...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Oh! I see. Sorry. Forgot to remove.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem comes from the `@ResponseBody` annotation. It tells Spring that the controller method will directly returns the body of the response. But it does not, because it returns a `ModelAndView`. So Spring tries to send the return of the method directly to client, (and should send and commit an empty response), then the ModelAndView handler tries to forward to a view with an already committed response causing the error.

You should at least remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation since it is not it what would be a synchronous equivalent.

But that's not all :

- you write `final DeferredResult<...` - IMHO the final should not be there since you will modify later the `DeferredResult`
- you try to test logged user in the scheduled asynchronous thread. This should not work, since common SecurityHelper use local thread storage to store this info, and actual processing will occur in another thread. Javadoc for `DeferredResult` even says : *For example, one might want to associate the user used to create the DeferredResult by extending the class and adding an addition property for the user. In this way, the user could easily be accessed later without the need to use a data structure to do the mapping.*
- you do not say how you configured async support. Spring Reference manual says : *The MVC Java config and the MVC namespace both provide options for configuring async request processing. `WebMvcConfigurer` has the method `configureAsyncSupport` while `<mvc:annotation-driven>` has an `<async-support>` sub-element.*

Comment: Changed nothing. Also I found out that it seems does not do `processQueue`. At least in debug it does not enter that method.

Comment: Indeed. There was a problem with `xml` configuration